# First: Converting object to an encodable object failed - then: HydratedCubit isn't hydrated

Tags: json, flutter, dart, bloc

the following situation: I want to make a ToDo list with a Cubit. That the ToDo list does not disappear after leaving the app, I found the package hydrated Bloc. When I created the HydratedCubit with the 2 override methods for the FromJson and ToJson, creating them Inside the ToDoState and executed it, I got an exception, "Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Todo'". After research I found out that JSON can't convert such a model and you have to overwrite these models with working From and To functions first. I tried this with the package "json serializable". Here I had to ask myself in which class I have to add the "@JsonSerializable()", inside the Todo model or the todo state, in which the error appears? I decided to add the @ for my todostate because adding it on the Todo model didn't change anything. After this package created me the "todo_list_state.g.dart" I don't get the error anymore, BUT: It also doesn't save the list, looks like HydratedCubit is being "ignored".  Here a few code snippets:

First, I show you the Todo Model:

```
Uuid uuid = const Uuid();

class Todo extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String desc;
  final double menge;

  Todo( {
    String? id,
    required this.desc,
    required this.menge,

  }) : id = id ?? uuid.v4();

  
}
```

I left out the to string and props...
As I mentioned before, I tried to add the JsonSerializableGenerator inside this class, but this didn't change something.
Here is my TodoListState:

```
part of 'todo_list_cubit.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class TodoListState extends Equatable {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  factory TodoListState.initial() {
    return TodoListState(todos: []);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic>toMap() => _$FoodListStateToMap(this, food);

  factory FoodListState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => _$FoodListStateFromMap(map);

  }
```

Here are the generated functions inside 'todo_list_state.g.dart':

```
TodoListState _$TodoListStateFromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TodoListState (
        todo: map['todo'] as List<TodoModel>,
    );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$TodoListStateToMap(TodoListState instance,  List<TodoModel> todo) {
    return {
        'todo': todo,
    };
}
```

At last here my Cubit functions where I override the From and To:

```
  @override
  TodoListState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoListState.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TodoListStatestate) {
    return state.toMap();
  }
```

So does anybody know why my Hydrated Cubit doesn't save my list? Or do I have to convert the Model but just dont know how?... Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Can you try adding `@JsonSerializable()` to Todo model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both model and states need to have `toJson` and `fromJson` methods. So the approach was right with using `JsonSerializable`. But converting objects to and from json is a very important thing to understand how to do without codegen tools. Those can be boilerplate and not always converting correctly complex objects. When doing it manually, it's also easier to debug. So in your case, additions to the model would be:

```
class Todo extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String desc;
  final double menge;

  Todo( {
    String? id,
    required this.desc,
    required this.menge,

  }) : id = id ?? uuid.v4();
  factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Todo(id: json['id'],
               desc: json['desc'],
               menge: json['menge'],);
    }
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'desc': desc,
      'menge': menge,
    };
  }
}
```

Then, in your states (again, I am not going to use `JsonSerializable`):

```
class TodoListState extends Equatable {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  TodoListState({this.todos = const <Todo>[]});

  factory TodoListState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var todos = <Todo>[];
    for (var item in json['todos']) {
      todos.add(Todo.fromJson(item));
    }
    return TodoListState(todos: todos);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var jsonTodoList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
    for (var item in todos) {
      jsonTodoList.add(item.toJson());
    }
    return {
      'todos': jsonTodoList,
    };
  }
}
```

Then in your Cubit nothing changes

```
  @override
  TodoListState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoListState.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TodoListState state) {
    return state.toJson();
  }
```

Except for you may want to add all sorts of null safety checks around the conversions, because I omitted all aspects not related to the topic of the question.

Comment: It adds the todo but still dont save it inside the "hydrated bloc" so after a Restart the added todos disappear...

Comment: Can you please share more of the cubit code?

Comment: Okay, what the hell :D I just recognized that your solution worked... i don't know what I saw on Dec 30, buuut now it works ? Good job!

Comment: Yes, you can. From the links you provided in your answer as proofs that it's not possible, can you please point out where that is actually stated?

Comment: Shared preferences is a storage service, and hydrated bloc is kind of a syntax sugar wrapper around another storage, hive. it's just good for it's purpose - persisting blocs states, so you don't write your own storage wrapper.

Comment: Appologies, but I do not have a possibility to write an entire app (even a small one) for you to prove a point. But I've done that in production. For you, on the other hand, it would be much easier to reference where exactly you see in issues you mentioned that it's not possible. Would you pleas do so?

Comment: Also a 2 minutes search gives us an example repository with hydrated bloc storing a list. Coincidentally, it's a todo app. https://dhruvnakum.xyz/hydrated-bloc-persist-and-restore-your-bloc-statedata

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't find this example on search. And thanks for letting me know we can store the list in hydrated bloc. I will edit my post accordingly. And I have referred you. Thanks again !!

Comment: @OlgaP A quick question: I want to do nearly the same but this time not with a todo model, just with an Object type Widget. I want to mark a Widget as favorit so when you press a button the navigator Push pushs you to the Widget provided inside the cubit. How do I convert a Widget inside a Hydrated bloc? :D is this easy to answere or shall I open a new request for that

Answer (score 0):

#### Persisting single instance of todo

*TodoCubit.dart*

```
class TodoCubit extends HydratedBloc<TodoCubit, TodoState> {
  TodoCubit() : super(ToDoInitial());

  @override
  TodoState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoState.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TodoState state) {
    return state.toJson();
  }

  saveTodo(String todo, String date) {
    emit(TodoState(presentTodo: Todo(todo: todo, day: date)));
  }
}
```

*ToDoState.dart*

```
class TodoState extends Equatable {
  final Todo presentTodo;

  const TodoState({required this.presentTodo});
  factory TodoState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoState(presentTodo: Todo(todo: json['todo'], day: json['day']));
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'todo': presentTodo.todo, 'day': presentTodo.day};

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [presentTodo];
}

class Todo {
  String todo;
  String day;
  Todo({required this.todo, required this.day});
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "todo: " + todo + " day: " + day;
  }
}

class ToDoInitial extends TodoState {
  ToDoInitial() : super(presentTodo: Todo(todo: '', day: ''));
}
```

*Home.dart*

```
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(state.presentTodo.toString()),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: Constants.kElevatedButtonStyle,
                      onPressed: () {
                        context
                            .read<TodoCubit>()
                            .saveTodo('Drink Water ', 'Tuesday');
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add Dummy Todo',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
```

*main.dart*

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => TodoCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme()
              .copyWith(backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(18, 26, 28, 1)),
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

#### To store multiple instance of todo that is list of todos refer this [example](https://dhruvnakum.xyz/hydrated-bloc-persist-and-restore-your-bloc-statedata)

@Credit for the example : @Olga P

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good to know! Yeah, I used already shared prefs for this case, but in a different way. Yours look way cleaner than mine, I'll check up that tomorrow, appreciate that.

Comment: Happy to know it worked for you ! I can share you the code which uses list of todos, but unfortunately it doesn't persist. Let me know if you want it , I'll produce the same for your reference